# ios how to implement SocketIO in iOS

Tags: ios, socket.io

I have a Server Address: http://someaddress.com/
by using SocketIO iOS library to connect to the above address with the correct protocol and namespace.

Socket Namespace: “/random”

Socket Event for random number: “capture”

This server uses SocketIO to send the randomly generated numbers every 4 seconds over the namespace “/random” with the event “capture”. How to access above address using SocketIO library. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely, there are iOS programming examples for socket.io.  Did you try any of those?  If so, what code did you use, what problems did you observe and where did you get stuck.  Since you've been around stack overflow a bit, I would expect that you would know that you're expected to do your own research on the problem, attempt a solution and come here only when you get stuck, not before writing a single line of code and without showing us any code.

Answer (score 4):

enum Socket: String{

```
case serverURL = "YOUR_SERVER_URL"
case namespace = "NAMESPACE NAME"
case eventName = "EVENT NAME"
```

}

/// Represents actual socket object with server url and namespace.

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: Socket.serverURL.rawValue)! as URL, config: [.nsp(Socket.namespace.rawValue)])

override init() {
    super.init()
}

/**
 This function used to establish connection with server.
 - Parameter: nil.
 - Returns: nil.
 */
func establishConnection() {
    socket.connect()
}

/**
 This function used to fetch next number from server.
 - Parameter: nil.
 - Returns: nil.
 */
func nextNumberFromServer(){
    socket.on(Socket.eventName.rawValue) {data, ack in
        if let number = data[0] as? NSNumber {
            print(number)
        }
    }
}

/**
 This function used to close connection with server.
 - Parameter: nil.
 - Returns: nil.
 */
func closeConnection() {
    socket.disconnect()
}
```